# how to ensure that the array of object ids has a unique user id in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a user profile which contains groups(array of object id for each group), when the user open any group should update the groups array in the user profile and push the group id, what I want is how to check if this group id already exists in the groups array before I update and push the id.
I'm using node.js and MongoDB for backend and react for frontend

Comment: Welcome to SO. To let others answer your question more easily, please provide some test data and some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to only add the group id if it does not already exist.

For example, `collection.updateOne({userId: 123}, {$addToSet: {groupId: 456}}`